# How to disable the checkbox/selection of p-treeTable row based on condition

Tags: angular, primeng

I need to disable the selection of row/checkbox in TreeTable of PrimeNG based on condition. that once the row is selected and some action performed, then does not allow to select same row. Selection mode is Checkbox.

I am using PrimeNG 5 and Angular 5.

**Update**

Achived the functionality what I needed  based on the [suggestion](https://github.com/ddvkid/ng-treetable/issues/8) to use the template checkbox. Not using the default selection/checkbox option.

Here is the plunker

```
<p-treeTable [value]="treedata" >
  <p-header>
  <input  type="checkbox" (click)="toggleNode()" />Toggle Expand
  <span *ngIf="isSelected"><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="isSelect" (click)="selectAll()" />Select All</span>
  <span *ngIf="isUnSelect" ><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="isUnSelect" (click)="unSelectAll()" />UnSelect All</span>
  </p-header>
  <p-column> 
  <ng-template let-row="rowData" let-i="rowIndex" pTemplate=body>
  <input *ngIf="row.data.type!='Folder'" type="checkbox" (click)="selectNode(row.data)" name="Select{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="row.data.selectable" [disabled]="row.data.type=='Folder'" />
  </ng-template>
  </p-column>
  <p-column field="name" header="Name"></p-column>
  <p-column field="size" header="Size"></p-column>
  <p-column field="type" header="Type"></p-column>

  </p-treeTable>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/umavnDBAzAleq8XIgiTO?p=preview

Comment: Can you give more details please ? In particular about the _action performed_

Comment: I have fixed by using the checkbox in template instead of the predefined one as mentioned in https://github.com/ddvkid/ng-treetable/issues/8